# Designing a 4-bit binary number divider circuit

Tags: digital-logic

I was given homework to design a 4-bit binary number divider which divides four bits by 5 (101 in binary). I tried looking at a lot of solutions without success. All I can use are basic gates, no registers and no sequential circuits. I have studied multipliers, adders and substractors but can't make a divider. Any help?

Comment: Did you study truth tables and Karnaugh maps?

Comment: Have you studied boolean arithmetic, can you construct boolean equations?

Comment: Yes I have studied them.

Comment: Thing is.. in this case you don't really need to do division, you just need to generate the correct four possible outputs (2 bits) for each of the possible 16 inputs (4 bits). Generally, that would be a terrible approach, but here it is what is called for.

Comment: Any other approach?

Answer (score 4):

It can be easily solved using its truth table and K-map.

As far as I understand the question only asks for the quotient.So in order to write the 
truth table you need only two output variables.This is because the maximum number that can 
be represented using 4 bits is 15 (1111), which when divided by 5 yields quotient 3 (0011).

Here is the truth table required.

[image]

A3 to A0 represent the input in binary.F1 and F0 represents the output in binary.

This table is easily obtained since numbers 0 to 4 upon division with 5 gives 0 quotient.
5 to 9 yields 1. 10 to 14 yields 2 and so on.

Now you can draw K-maps for F1 and F0.

If you need you can form expression for remainder also in a similar manner.Just remember that,in that case you require 3 output bits, as maximum remainder upon division by 5 is 4 (100).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Newstein in this particular case the best soloution is to treat this as a general logic problem, write out the truth table and then solve it and I strongly suspect that is what your instructor intended you to do.

You ask in your comments "any other approach". The "truth table" soloution works for small values but as the number of bits increases it gets harder and harder to solve.

To demonstrate this lets consider an extended version of your problem. Dividing an 6 bit number by 5.

The largest possible 6 bit number is 63. 63/5 = 12 remainder 3 so we need 4 bits of output (numbered 0 to 3 with 0 being the LSB and 3 being the MSB). Lets think about how we could do this in a computer program.

To express this program I will use a psuedocode with a C-like syntax with ^ used for power and with [] used to access individual bits of a number.

```
remainder=input
bit=3
while (bit > 0) {
  if (remainder >= (2^bit)*5) {
    output[bit] = 1;
    remainder -= (2^bit)*5;
  } else {
    output[bit] = 0
  }
  bit--;
}
```

So can we turn this into combinatorial digital logic? Firstly we have to get rid of the loop. Since the loop has a fixed number of iterations we can unroll it.

```
remainder=input
if (remainder >= (2^3)*5) {
  output[3] = 1;
  remainder -= (2^3)*5;
} else {
  output[3] = 0
}
if (remainder >= (2^2)*5) {
  output[2] = 1;
  remainder -= (2^2)*5;
} else {
  output[2] = 0
}
if (remainder >= (2^1)*5) {
  output[1] = 1;
  remainder -= (2^1)*5;
} else {
  output[1] = 0
}
if (remainder >= 2^0*5) {
  output[0] = 1;
  remainder -= (2^0)*5;
} else {
  output[0] = 0
}
```

Ok,  we got rid to the loop but we still have those nasty-looking if statements. Lets replace them with ternary operators.

```
remainder=input
output[3] = (remainder >= (2^3)*5);
tmp = remainder - (2^3)*5;
remainder = output[3] ? tmp : remainder;
output[2] = (remainder >= (2^2)*5);
tmp = remainder - (2^2)*5;
remainder = output[2] ? tmp : remainder;
output[1] = (remainder >= (2^1)*5);
tmp = remainder - (2^1)*5;
remainder = output[1] ? tmp : remainder;
output[0] = (remainder >= (2^0)*5);
tmp = remainder - (2^0)*5;
remainder = output[0] ? tmp : remainder;
```

Ok, that comparision still looks nasty, can we get rid of it? yes we can, we can exploit the properties of wraparound on overflow to our advantage.

```
remainder=input
tmp = remainder - (2^3)*5;
output[3] = ! tmp[3]
remainder = output[3] ? tmp : remainder;
tmp = remainder - (2^2)*5;
output[2] = ! tmp[2]
remainder = output[2] ? tmp : remainder;
tmp = remainder - (2^1)*5;
output[1] = ! tmp[1]
remainder = output[1] ? tmp : remainder;
tmp = remainder - (2^0)*5;
output[0] = ! tmp[0]
remainder = output[0] ? tmp : remainder;
```

Since we now have no loops, if statements or other such complications we can now modify our program so each variable is assigned exactly once.

```
tmp3 = input - (2^3)*5;
output[3] = ! tmp3[3]
remainder3 = output[3] ? tmp3 : input;
tmp2 = remainder3 - (2^2)*5;
output[2] = ! tmp2[2]
remainder2 = output[2] ? tmp2 : remainder3;
tmp1 = remainder2 - (2^1)*5;
output[1] = ! tmp1[1]
remainder1 = output[1] ? tmp1 : remainder2;
tmp0 = remainder1 - (2^0)*5;
output[0] = ! tmp0[0]
remainder = output[0] ? tmp0 : remainder1;
```

We can now replace the variables in our program with signals and the statements with subtractors, not gates and multiplexers. The subtractors and multiplexers can be built out of basic logic gates.